# How to show user count of discord bot in html

Tags: html, css, discord.js, dashboard, tracking

I made a website for my discord bot.
I made this in HTML:

```
            <div class="container-fluid text-white">
                <div class="row row-cols-3 justify-content-center" style="color: var(--secondary-text-color);">
                    <div class="col-auto col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center pb-5 pt-5 number-item love_counter">
                        <h1 class="love_count" style="font-size: 70px;"><strong>100</strong></h1>
                        <h4 style="color: var(--main-color);margin-top: -6px;">Total Servers</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto col-lg-4 text-center align-self-center pb-5 pt-5 love_counter">
                        <h1 class="love_count" style="font-size: 70px;"><strong>2500</strong></h1>
                        <h4 style="color: var(--main-color);margin-top: -6px;">Total Users</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This show that the bot is 100+ servers and the total users are 2500+. This is an example, because I don't know how to automatically tracks the members/server. Does anyone knows how to automatically track those stats?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service; we aren't just going to write an entire feature for your bot for you. As for how to track those stats, I assume you only need to fetch the bot's server and user count whenever this HTML page is loaded. Look into a templating engine such as [ejs](https://ejs.co/) or [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/). Templating allows you to define some data and then use it via placeholders in your HTML (e.g. define `serverCount` data on your bot's node server using a templating engine, and then access it in the HTML via a placeholder like `{{ serverCount }}`).

Comment: Alternatively, you could setup a GET request handler on your bot's node.js server and regularly make a GET request from the HTML page to the server (perhaps every 5 minutes or so) requesting the data you need, and then update the `h1`'s with the data you receive. You would get the data via discord.js (e.g. `guild.memberCount`).